# Создание локально развернутого чата

Tags: веб-программирование, чат

Всех приветствую! Стоит следующая задача: создать локально развернутый аналог ChatGPT (на ~30 пользователей). Нет понимания, какой стек технологий лучше использовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь варианты, ссылки на информацию и т.п. В приоритете, конечно, бек на Python.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь варианты, ссылки на информацию и
> т.п.

Для начала гуглим "ChatGPT API".
А дальше - по квалификации/возможностям

Comment: Признаю, неправильно задал вопрос. С сеткой проблем нет, у меня квантованная моделька уже в докере лежит. Но я фиговенько шарю в вебе. Сначала мне показалось, что надо использовать websocket (чат же как никак), но потом пришло понимание. Как организовать серверную часть? Если моделька все равно под Python, легче на django?